# while creating object of a class in another class having only parameterized Ctor "error: x is not a type"

Tags: c++, constructor, parameterized

When I try to create an object of class A having only parametrized Constructor in class B, I get following errors:

```
A ob(5); error: expected identifier before numeric constant  
A ob(x); error: x is not a type 

class A {
    public:
    int z;
    A(int y){z = y;}
};
class B {
    public:
    int x;
    A ob(5); or A ob(x);//This line is creating a problem
};
```

I searched for the same and got that we can solve this problem by writing

```
A ob;
B():ob(5);
OR
int x;
A ob;
B():ob(x);   //here x will be uninitialized though
```

But I am thinking why it was giving error in the prior case. Can someone explain in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign default value to class member in C++. You need to define constructor.

```
class A {
    public:
    int z;
    A(int y){z = y;}
};
class B {
    public:
    int x;
    A ob; //
    B() : x(5), ob(x) {}
};
```

Comment: A ob(5); or A ob(x);//This line is creating a problem. Why this is failing?

Comment: Since there is no default Ctor in class A
How it is allowing A ob;
B() : x(5), ob(x) {} What is happening here, can you elaborate